# Where to place logic for parsing data before saving to database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm taking open data about all the countries in the world and need to be able to parse through that JSON file in order to pull out relevant content for each country and store that into my database.

I'm a little unclear about Where I should be writing the logic to parse through that data and save each relevant part for each country in my database - in the model or controller? I almost put it in the root index of my controller to begin parsing as soon as the user visits, but I just have a feeling that this goes against the rails convention of fat models, skinny controllers.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: service objects. check interactor and/or troupe gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right that placing all the logic in your controller will violate skinny controllers.

One way to do it is by methods on your models which parse data from the api:

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.create_from_kittypix_api(data, &block)
      model = self.new(attrs_from_some_api(data))
      yield(model, data) if block_given?
      model
    end

    def self.attrs_from_kittypix_api(data)
      {
         foo: data[:bar]
      }
    end 
end
```

The drawback here is that your models end up knowing a bit too much about the external API, and creating several models at once can lead to confusion about responsibility.

A newer approach is [using services](https://netguru.co/blog/service-objects-in-rails-will-help), which are plain old ruby objects which take an input and accompish a given task.

```
class KittypixImportService
  def self.call(kitty_pix_id)
    client = KittyPixClient.new
    result = client.get_kitty(id: kitty_pix_id)
    Cat.new(
      foo: result['bar']
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For myself, my Rails work has evolved into more of an MVCS type approach. I keep my controllers as skinny and light as I can (to me, they're nothing more than the "traffic cops" of the framework).

I try to also keep my models similarly light where added methods either represent the model and its data or its behavior. For example, in a `User` model with first and last name attributes/fields, I typically add a method called `name` that concatenates first and last.

If the program requirements fall outside of those or similar use-cases, I tend toward using Services that I store in `/app/services`.

The classic, to-do-esque example, at least for me, is searching a model, which I rarely place in a model. Instead, I receive the search request in the controller (of course) and then send the params and any other relevant details to a service class and let it do the work.

Here's a really basic search example ... really basic :)!

```
# app/controllers/some_cleverly_named_controller.rb
def index 
  @search_results = ClientSearch.call(params)
  # ... 
end

# app/services/client_search.rb
class ClientSearch 
  def self.call(params)
    ModelName.where(related_id: params[:related_model_id],  active: params[:status]).order("id #{params[:sort_order]}, model_name.last_name #{params[:sort_order]}").includes(:related_model)
  end 
end
```

I have a super-simple, but boringly named [gem that generates a service](https://github.com/imageaid/rails_service_generator)  and an rspec template for it, just in case you try the Services approach.

If interest, do a web search on "Rails Services" and there's a wealth of data!

Good luck!

Comment: Totally! Had to LOL when I submitted mine and reloaded the page and saw yours :)!